# How to update DocProperty fields with Word js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing an Office 2016 Addin using Word js 1.3. The addin allows to define custom properties and save their value.

I'd like to add a button in the UI of my Addin that updates all usages of DocProperty fields (see pic 1) in the document which use custom properties that the user added. Basically the button should update the fields (see pic 2).

I mean these things here:

[image: DocProperty Field]

[image: Update Field in document]

I can't wrap the fields in ContentControls and then update those. The documents come pre-configured with some custom properties and their content must not be changed.

Comment: As far as I can see, this isn't suppoted in the JS APIs. There is a request on MS UserVoice for adding fields. I've posted a comment to it to not forget to support updating fields, as well. You may want to upvote: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16473235-adding-field-codes-for-word-using-word-javascript

Comment: @CindyMeister I forgot about this. Would be great if they add support for DocProperty fields; I could revive and finish my project.

Comment: Well... You know you can configure content controls to be non-editable?